# Method of Undetermined Coefficients Using Complex Arithmetic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just got done reading through the section on the technique of undetermined coefficients using complex arithmetic in the fourth edition of Nagle and Saff's book, and I'm having trouble applying what I read to problems. Here's the section I read:
[image]

[image]

I'm currently trying to use the procedure in the reading to determine the particular solutions to the following ODEs:

(a) $$y''+y=e^{-x}[\cos(2x)-3\sin(2x)]$$

(b) $$y''-2y'+10y=xe^x\sin(3x)$$

I'm stuck though. For the first problem I have the auxiliary equation $r^2+1=0\Rightarrow r=\pm i$, but I don't understand where to go from here. It would be nice if someone could work out an example, not necessarily these ones, but perhaps one such as

$$y''-3y'+15y=te^t\cos(5t)$$

I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted?

Answer (score 1):

For (a), a particular solution is of the form $e^{-x}(A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x))$, with $A,B$ to be determined.

For (b), ordinarily it would be $(Ax+B)e^x(C\cos(3x)+D\sin(3x))$, but $e^x\cos(3x)$ and $e^x\sin(3x)$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation, so you have to use $(Ax^2+Bx)e^x(C\cos(3x)+D\sin(3x))$. Well, try it, see if it works, it has been a while since I last taught this material.

Comment: My fault, I had meant to respond. I didn't end up doing the questions but I will post my response later. I got caught up doing some homework and other assignments. I'm comfortable using the tables to solve Method of Undetermined Coefficients, my main issue was trying to do them using complex arithmetic so I don't have to memorize forms or stuff like that.